# Como contar los días de una semana de una fecha sin incluir sábado y domingo en visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Como contar los días de una semana de una fecha dada hasta fecha today sin incluir sábado y domingo en `visual basic`?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hola Acd. ¿Puedes ofrecer algunos ejemplos concretos con los resultados esperados? Igualmente, ¿puedes aclarar cual *Visual Basic* usas? Asumo que es *VB.NET*, por la etiqueta *Visual Studio 2015*. Pero pregunto porque la etiqueta *visual-basic-6* no encaja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Public Function ContadorDiaLaboral(ByVal fechaInicial As Date)
        Dim contadorDias As Integer = 0
        While fechaInicial < Now.Date
            If fechaInicial.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Saturday Or fechaInicial.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
                contadorDias = contadorDias + 1
            End If
            fechaInicial = fechaInicial.AddDays(1)
        End While
        Return contadorDias
    End Function
```

Comment: Describe tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim _responseduedate As DateTime = Datetime.Now.AddDays(20)

Dim _numero As Integer = 0  
If Not (_responseduedate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday OrElse _responseduedate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday) 
 Then       
    _numero += 1    
End If
```

Comment: Detalla tu respuesta